# Vue array in array change index for secod array

Tags: javascript, vue.js, v-for

I have an array:

```
[{ title: 'title 1', options: ['a', 'b'] },
{ title: 'title 2', options: ['c', 'd'] },
{ title: 'title 3', options: ['e', 'f'] }]
```

And I render this array using `v-for`:

```
<div v-for="(item, i) in content" :key="item.title">
    <div>
        <div>{{ item.title }}</div>
        <div :class="{'selected-item': i === selectedIndex}">
            {{ item.options[selectedOptionIndex] }}
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

When I change the value of the `selectedOptionIndex`, it changes for each index (for title 1, title 2 and title 3). I want change option only for e.g `title 1`. How I can fix it?

Comment: you can achieve that with an array with same indexes as your items array. `selectedOptionIndex = ['a', 'c', 'e']` (to get first option of each item for example) then as you iterate over items with index `i` you can call `{{ item.options[selectedOptionIndex[i]] }}`

Comment: but maybe you should work with an indexed object instead of an array `{item1 : {title: 'title1', options: {...}}, item2: {title: 'title2, options: {...}}, ...}` and work with a `selectedOptionIndex` as object with the same keys: `{item1: 'a', item2: 'c', item3: 'e'}`